# Display different content depending on referrer value

Tags: javascript

I would like to display different content depending on the javascript `referrer` value. If someone came from a certain site, show ad. If they came from google, show nothing.

I found this code, but it won't load whatever site I put in the code:

```
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?reddit\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
  alert("Came from reddit");
}
```

so i try

```
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?mysite\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
  alert("Came from my site");
}
```

But I don't actually need an alert. I need to display and ad where people must view it before they can go into the site.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with the referrer or displaying different content based on referrer... it's how do I force my visitors to view an ad before continuing to my page?

Comment: @sachleen He basically wants to display content *dynamically*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `indexOf` instead:

```
var ref = document.referrer;

if (!ref.indexOf("mysite.com") != -1) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client="ca-pub-3604220145521433";google_ad_slot‌​="0430765382";google_ad_width=300;google_ad_height=250;</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>')
}
```

Comment: It wont load, i have put your code into index of mysite.com and reffered it from footer from that other site where i need refferer to show.

Comment: @RenatoMirkovic You're setting the value of `ref` to `document.referrer`, right?

Comment: this is how it looks http://gyazo.com/5d7c6314f17dcc51388b5d7418dde578.png?1358106251

Comment: @RenatoMirkovic You have to define the `ref` variable before using it. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah that works now, but now i need to put ad instead of alert there, and im pretty useless when it comes to javascript

Comment: @RenatoMirkovic What kind of advertisement? From where? Be more specific please.

Comment: i just need to put a window with an ad instead of the alert, something similar to "like to see" wordpress plugins, but window with an advertisement banner

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client="ca-pub-3604220145521433";google_ad_slot="0430765382";google_ad_width=300;google_ad_height=250;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script> i need that to popup instead of that alert things

Comment: now i get "') } " in the header of the site without that ad popup.

Comment: @RenatoMirkovic I can't do anything about that. You have to figure out that by yourself.